# How to align content in center using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS & trying to create my own custom tristate checkbox editor for [SlickGrid](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3a-compound-editors.html) but the alignment of content is not correct, I want to place the `checkmark` and `hyphen` in center of a square, I tried applying css `padding: 2px` to `partial` & `checked` class but it didn't help.

This is how it displays in Grid.

[image]
[image]

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `line-height` and `text-align: center`.

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
  <span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
  <span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution its a bit nasty.. if you resize the div .multi-checkbox, it will be a messy..

Answer (score 2):

Since those characters/symbols are part of a font, they are aligned like letters, i.e. there can be space above and below them, depending on the particular character (different for many characters of a font, and different for the two characters you are using in your example).

But you can use `text-align: center` for the horizontal centering and a `padding` setting that adds up to the same amount on all four sides to move the characters up a bit. In my example below I used `padding: 0px 2px 4px 2px`

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0 2px 4px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* and vertically */
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {background: #fff}
.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {content: "\2010"}
.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {content: "\2713"}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
  <span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
  <span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can align content on the center using **Flexbox** like this:

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat. I like the _flexbox_ way

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks, I'm happy to have helped you

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you.

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height:15px;
}
.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}
.multi-checkbox .check:after{
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}
.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.unchecked {
  background: #fff;
}

.multi-checkbox .check.partial:after {
  content: "\2010";
}

.multi-checkbox .check.checked:after {
  content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check partial" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>

<div class="multi-checkbox">
<span class="check checked" hidefocus="" style=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
.multi-checkbox .check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```